# opening and closing connection for every row in gridview asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am new to programming and to stackoverflow. I need help on sql server 2008 and asp.net. I need to save multiple rows in database using gridview in asp.net. So for every row in gridview I ahve to open and close the connection in asp.net. Does opening and closing for every row has disadvantages. If any please tell.

Answer (score 0):

option 1:

fill the datatable with new rows send it to your DAL method , open the connection once and add rows one by one and after adding all rows close the connection

option 2

again fill the datatable with new rows send it to your dal method , open the connection and use sqlbulkcopy class to add the rows at once.

and best approch is to use sqlbulkcopy

more one sqlbulkcopy can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)